# Image not getting in post data in Magento one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Why I am not getting image data in post record `\app\design\frontend\themename\mytheme\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml`

```
<form id="co-billing-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <!-Custom Attribute->
    <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="billing:ssn" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="custom[ssn]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getQuote()->getSsn()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="billing:ssn" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="image"><?php echo $this->__('Profile image') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input name="custom[image]" id="image" title="<?php echo $this->__('Image') ?>"
                   type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-Custom Attribute->
 </form>
```

I am getting the below array in post data where i am not getting image data

```
     Array
(
    [billing_address_id] => 2
    [billing] => Array
        (
            [address_id] => 91
            [firstname] => test 
            [middlename] => j
            [lastname] => j
            [company] => j
            [street] => Array
                (
                    [0] => adsad
                    [1] => asd
                )

            [city] => asdasd
            [region_id] => 17
            [region] => 
            [postcode] => 233232
            [country_id] => US
            [telephone] => 324324
            [fax] => 
            [use_for_shipping] => 1
        )

    [custom] => Array
        (
            [ssn] => 123123
        )
```

Comment: have you tried $_FILES ? i am not sure you are trying to retrieve from session or posting Data , if you are posting then images data will be in $_FILES

Comment: where you want me to use : I am posting data

Comment: wherever you are want to save data from (do a print_r($_FILES) after you are printing that array you included above)

Comment: getting empty array Array
(
)